# RecyclerView Adapter Layout not showing icon

Tags: android, imageview, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

First things first, here goes one screenshot (sorry by the poor paint editing):

[image]

Well as you may have noticed, only the middle line there is an icon (green circle), however, I'm setting up the icons of all rows, or maybe I think I am.
The icon can be green or red, the first line should show an Green icon and the last, one red icon, but none of them shows anything, only the second row, so my question is, why only one of my rows shows the icon properly, and of course, how can I fix it?

Here goes my adapter code:

```
//imports and stuff     
public class EstablishmentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EstablishmentViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<EstablishmentModel> establishmentList;
    private Context context;
    private boolean hasPermission;
    private int selectedPosition = 0;

    public EstablishmentAdapter(ArrayList<EstablishmentModel> establishmentList, Context context, boolean hasPermission) {
        this.establishmentList = establishmentList;
        this.context = context;
        this.hasPermission = hasPermission;
    }

    @Override
    public EstablishmentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        EstablishmentViewHolder viewHolder;
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_adapter_establishment, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new EstablishmentViewHolder(v, (byte)0, hasPermission);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EstablishmentViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final EstablishmentModel item = establishmentList.get(position);

        Log.d(((EstablishmentActivity)context).logTagDebug, "Position: "+ String.valueOf(position));
        Log.d(((EstablishmentActivity)context).logTagDebug, "ViewHolder: "+ String.valueOf(holder.getAdapterPosition()));

        setUpTextFieldsItemRow(holder, item);
        new ImageDonwloaderTask(holder.ivIcon).execute(item.getIconUrl());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
                selectedPosition = position;
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);

                //Se a gente botar o full, fazer switch case aqui
                setUpPayContractTypeAction(item);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpTextFieldsItemRow(EstablishmentViewHolder holder, EstablishmentModel item) {
        holder.tvClosingTime.setText(item.getClosingTime());
        holder.tvOpeningTime.setText(item.getOpeningTime());
        holder.tvName.setText(item.getName());
        holder.tvType.setText(item.getType());

        if (item.isOpened()) {
            holder.ivWorkingStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_dot_green);
        } else {
            holder.ivWorkingStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_dot_red);
        }
    }

    private void setUpPayContractTypeAction(EstablishmentModel item) {
        if(item.isOpened()) {
            PaymentInfoViewModel p = new PaymentInfoViewModel();
            p.setIdEstablishment(item.getIdEstablishment());
            p.setNameEstablishment(item.getName());

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CardNumberActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ConstantsUtils.PARAM_INTENT_PAYMENT_INFO, p);

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            EstablishmentActivity activity = ((EstablishmentActivity) context);

            String title = String.format(context.getString(R.string.str_msg_error_closed_establishment_title),
                    item.getName());
            String message = String.format(context.getString(R.string.str_msg_error_closed_establishment_msg),
                    item.getName(), item.getOpeningTime(), item.getClosingTime());

            activity.buildAlert(title, message).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return establishmentList.size();
    }
}
```

Here goes the activity layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dl_menu"
    android:elevation="7dp"
    tools:context=".view.activity.EstablishmentActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/srl_refresh_establishments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_establishments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_menu_drawer"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#ffffff">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Item row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_establishment_icon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_horizontal_small"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_horizontal_small"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_horizontal_small"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_horizontal_small"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_vertical_small"
        >
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_establishment_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_vertical_normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_large"
            android:text="Bar Alternativo"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            >
        </TextView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_vertical_small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_establishment_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_tiny"
                android:text="Pub / Bar"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_60_percent"
                >
            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_establishment_working_status_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/img_dot_green"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_horizontal_big"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_horizontal_big"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_establishment_type"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_establishment_type"
                android:layout_width="17dp"
                android:layout_height="17dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_establishment_opening_time"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_vertical_normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_very_tiny"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_30_percent"
                android:text="19:00"
                >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_establishment_separator_time"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_vertical_normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_very_tiny"
                android:text="@string/str_screen_txt_hyphen"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_30_percent"
                >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_establishment_closing_time"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_vertical_normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_very_tiny"
                android:text="02:00"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_30_percent"
                >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_establishment_place_distance"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_horizontal_normal"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_horizontal_normal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_very_tiny"
                >
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
I tried editing the size of the icon, and it reflected in all rows size, so I suppose the ImageView is in the laoyut, but without image.

**EDIT 2**
Red and green dot added:
[image]
[image]

However I don't think image is the problem, because first row should display green dot, but it doesn't.

**EDIT 3**
Here goes my viewholder:

```
public class EstablishmentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView ivIcon;
    public TextView tvName;
    public ImageView ivWorkingStatus;
    public TextView tvOpeningTime;
    public TextView tvClosingTime;
    public TextView tvPlaceDistance;
    public TextView tvType;

    public byte idContractType;

    public EstablishmentViewHolder(View itemView, byte idContractType {
        super(itemView);

        this.ivIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_establishment_icon);
        this.tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_establishment_name);
        this.ivWorkingStatus = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_establishment_working_status_icon);
        this.tvOpeningTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_establishment_opening_time);
        this.tvClosingTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_establishment_closing_time);
        this.tvPlaceDistance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_establishment_place_distance);
        this.tvType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_establishment_type);
        this.idContractType = idContractType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your xml for the list item?

Comment: Yes, just a moment - EDIT: Done

Comment: My first thought is the relative layout containing `iv_establishment_working_status_icon` is too short to display the icon. For testing try making the icon height and width 5dp or something instead of 17dp and see if it shows up

Comment: I did that, only the second row keep showing the icon, looks like something is hiding it.

Comment: debug the code with either breakpoints or log messages and check how often `holder.ivWorkingStatus.setImageResource` is called and for which row.

Comment: can you share your image resource R.drawable img_dot_red?

Comment: @P.Rai I don't think that's the problem, check last line in the question.

Comment: Are you doing anything special in EstablishmentViewHolder?

Comment: @Luksprog I don't think so, I've pasted it.

Comment: You didn't posted that holder class completely(at least from the way you instantiated it). Anyway, it's hard to tell what's going on. Your best bet would be to start small, remove the code(any code) that touches the problematic ImageView, set it with a basic drawable(like your app icon)  so you can see it and then go from there until the problem appears.

Comment: Try to give a scaleType of fitCenter to your image view in xml file. Although it does not make sense because image is visible in 2nd row. But try it once and let me know.

Comment: @guisantogui Few things to try: First, give the `TextView` with id `tv_establishment_type` a solid background - `android:background="#ff0000"`. That will check if the `red/green dot` is being pushed off-screen. Second, comment out the `if-else` code - does the green icon show up in all the rows? Third, set ``android:background="#ff0000"`` on the `ImageView`. One of these should help you locate the issue. Finally, if none of these work, comment out `android:layout_toRightOf` & `android:layout_toEndOf` and work from  there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you align the left of image view to right of text view !!!

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_vertical_small"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_establishment_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_tiny"
            android:text="Pub / Bar"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_60_percent"
            >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_establishment_working_status_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/img_dot_green"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_horizontal_big"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_horizontal_big"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_establishment_type"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_establishment_type"
            android:layout_width="17dp"
            android:layout_height="17dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

as the text grows, you won't see any image. try using Linearlayout with gravity right and also set the weight of textview to 1

Answer (score 1):

Note the match_parent in the root of linearlayout and the relative layout that now is a linearlayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_establishment_icon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_horizontal_small"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_horizontal_small"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_horizontal_small"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_horizontal_small"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_vertical_small">
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_establishment_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_vertical_normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_large"
            android:text="Bar Alternativo"
            android:textColor="@color/black">
        </TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_vertical_small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_establishment_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_tiny"
                android:text="Pub / Bar"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_60_percent">
            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_establishment_working_status_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/img_dot_green"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_horizontal_big"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_horizontal_big"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_establishment_type"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_establishment_type"
                android:layout_width="17dp"
                android:layout_height="17dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_establishment_opening_time"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_vertical_normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_very_tiny"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_30_percent"
                android:text="19:00"
                >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_establishment_separator_time"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_vertical_normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_very_tiny"
                android:text="@string/str_screen_txt_hyphen"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_30_percent"
                >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_establishment_closing_time"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_vertical_normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_very_tiny"
                android:text="02:00"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_30_percent"
                >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_establishment_place_distance"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_horizontal_normal"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_horizontal_normal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_very_tiny"
                >
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You haven't set image resource anywhere in onBindViewHolder. Either set the image resource directly in onBindViewHolder or move the if condition out of the method setUpPayContractTypeAction**

Just notice the method **setUpPayContractTypeAction** which contains following if condition and you have called method setUpPayContractTypeAction in **onClick** event, it means image resources will be set on item click event.

```
if (item.isOpened()) {

  holder.ivWorkingStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_dot_green);

} else {

  holder.ivWorkingStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_dot_red);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the margin_horizontal_big at the start of the image causing the trouble.please try removing the margin and align to right of parent and try.

Also, in case you are making the view invisible programmatically anywhere inside an if condition, you have to implement the else code too, otherwise the adapter just copies that visibility state to adjacent list items, too.